# My post request req.body turns empty on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

My post request to create new item, turns me with new item created. It is working well in localhost.
[image]

But when I deploy my app on heroku and then post request **Status Code: 503 Service Unavailable** , but empty **res.body**. Here also my server.js file

**server.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const items = require("./routes/api/items");
const users = require("./routes/api/user");
const auth = require("./routes/api/auth");

app.use(express.json());

require("dotenv").config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB).then(console.log("connected"));

app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/items", items);
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/auth", auth);
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

**item.js**

```js
router.post("/createTeam", auth, (req, res) => {
  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name,
  });
  newItem.save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});
```

**itemActions.js**

```
export const addItems = (input) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/items/createTeam", input, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_ITEM,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, "GET_ERRORS")
      )
    );
};
```

Also my heroku logs are here when I create new Team

```
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743015+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'majority\"' found in replica set configuration
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743023+00:00 app[web.1]:     at MessageStream.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:463:30)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743024+00:00 app[web.1]:     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743024+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processIncomingData (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:108:16)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743024+00:00 app[web.1]:     at MessageStream._write (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:28:9)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743025+00:00 app[web.1]:     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743026+00:00 app[web.1]:     at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743026+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743026+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743027+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743027+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9) {
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743028+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 79,
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743030+00:00 app[web.1]:   codeName: 'UnknownReplWriteConcern',
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743030+00:00 app[web.1]:   errInfo: {
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743031+00:00 app[web.1]:     writeConcern: { w: 'majority"', wtimeout: 0, provenance: 'clientSupplied' }
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743031+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743032+00:00 app[web.1]:   result: {
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743032+00:00 app[web.1]:     n: 1,
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743032+00:00 app[web.1]:     opTime: { ts: new Timestamp({ t: 1638611515, i: 13 }), t: 104 },
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743033+00:00 app[web.1]:     electionId: new ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000068"),
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743033+00:00 app[web.1]:     ok: 1,
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743034+00:00 app[web.1]:     writeConcernError: {
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743034+00:00 app[web.1]:       code: 79,
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743034+00:00 app[web.1]:       codeName: 'UnknownReplWriteConcern',
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743035+00:00 app[web.1]:       errmsg: `No write concern mode named 'majority\\"' found in replica set configuration`,
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743035+00:00 app[web.1]:       errInfo: [Object]
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743036+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743036+00:00 app[web.1]:     '$clusterTime': {
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743036+00:00 app[web.1]:       clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1638611515, i: 13 }),
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743036+00:00 app[web.1]:       signature: [Object]
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743037+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743037+00:00 app[web.1]:     operationTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1638611515, i: 13 })
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743037+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2021-12-04T09:51:55.743037+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

**SOLUTION**
I removed '' or "" from **MONGO_DB** which is on heroku config vars, and solved

Comment: What headers are you adding in the request?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I didnt add any header when I call it in axios. Also I added how I call it

Comment: The heroku logs show that the error is related to mongo. It is nothing to do with request object.